# Regular Expression for the Pattern?

Tags: regex

I'm required to write a regular expression that has the following rules:

- Digits between 1 to 4
- hyphen (**only one** and can occur at any position)
- Length of Text must be less than or equal to 6 (including the potential hyphen)
- May end with a letter or a number, but **not** a hyphen.

Some **valid** examples are:

- 1-3411
- 12-413
- 123-2A
- 11-1

These examples are **invalid**:

- 12--11 ( since it contains two hyphens)
- 1-2345 ( since it contains number 5)
- 11-2311 ( since length is more than 6)

The RegEx that I wrote is:

```
^[1-4]-[1-4]{4}|^[1-4]{2}-[1-4]{3}|^[1-4]{3}-[1-4]{2}|^[1-4]{4}-[1-4]
```

However, this does not seem to be working, and it doesn't handle the case of a single character being is present in the end.

Can some some please help me determine a way of handling this?

<> 
is character occurs in last position then before character we must have a digit not hypen .

i.e 11-a ( must fail)
    11-1a (must pass)

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Is this a class assignment, or a real-world problem?  It may make more sense to use multiple regexes rather than trying to force it all into one.

Comment: its a real world probelm andy lester

Comment: I'm Using Sql Server . Calling DLL from SSMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:[^-\n]*-){2})(?:[1-4-]{1,5}[1-4]|[1-4-]{1,5}[a-zA-Z])$
```

You can handle that using a `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/16

Comment: this expression evalutes true for 1-23q2(only in last position i must have a alphabet),1-22aa (more than one alphabet - must contain only one alphabet ) :(

Comment: can u plz read my above comment and reply ? i didnt understand.

Comment: 11223- seems to pass but it should fail since (it ends with hyphen) must only end with alphabet or number not with hyphen

Comment: yes . Sorry i forgot mention one more condn . The text may or may not have a hyphen . so it shud also pass 123123. This RegEx Fails.I accept its my fault not mentioning it.

Comment: ur a life saver .Thank u very much .

Comment: <<ONE MORE CHANGE >> 
is character occurs in last position then before character we must have a digit not hypen .

i.e 11-a ( must fail)
    11-1a (must pass)

Comment: @user3326623 `^(?!(?:[^-\n]*-){2})(?:[1-4-]{1,5}[1-4]|[1-4-]{1,4}[1-4][a-zA-Z])$`

Comment: can u give tell how to use this regex along with words ? Say i Have 11-11a   (space here) Avenue (Word) .So this regex doesnt match 11-11a Avenue.I need to change it to match for the above case . i.e space and a word after your regex.

Comment: can u check my above comment

Comment: @user3326623 https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/25 `^(?!(?:[^\n -]*-){2})(?:[1-4-]{1,5}[1-4]|[1-4-]{1,4}[1-4][a-zA-Z])(?:\s+\w+)?$`

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a complex requirement, it is always *easy* to use lookarrounds to form an `and`-pattern matching each condition at the same time. Sometimes you need to split up ONE condition into two:

- Base-Match: 6 or less digits: `^.{1,6}$`
- (AND) Only `1-4` and hyphen and letter: `^[1-4a-z\-]+$` (not accurate, requires next line)
- (AND) First 1...5 elements NO Letter: `^[1-4\-]{1,5}[1-4a-z]$`
- (AND) No double hypen and not at the end: `^[^-]*-[^-]+$`

Putting all together leads to:

```
(?=^[1-4\-]{1,5}[1-4a-z]$)(?=^[^-]*-[^-]*$)(?=^[1-4a-z\-]+$)^.{1,6}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9oeJ5mpskk4dNb34)